# Using jQuery, how can I grab value from href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of links on my page, in the format:

```
<a href="/q/10/Title">Title</a>
```

How can I grab the "10" from this link and use it as a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('a').attr('href')` to get the path, and then you can use `String#split` to break it up.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Better documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split (See: http://promotejs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for 1 or more digits (`[\d]+`) with a **[regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)** in the `href` **[attribute](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/)** of the `a` tag:

```
​var theNumber = /[\d]+/.exec( $("a").attr("href") );​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6VLe/)

The above will find the first number in the `href` of the first `a` tag. You can of course use other jQuery selectors.